# Combining multiple NSArrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

How can I combine multiple NSArrays into one array with alternating values? For example.

Array One: Orange, Apple, Pear

Array Two: Tree, Shrub, Flower

Array Three: Blue, Green, Yellow

The final array would need to be:
Orange, Tree, Blue, Apple, Shrub, Green, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the arrays are all of the same length:

```
NSUInteger numberOfArrays = 3;
NSUInteger arrayLength = [arrayOne length];
NSMutableArray *finalMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(arrayLength * numberOfArrays)];
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++) {
    [finalMutableArray addObject:[arrayOne objectAtIndex:index]];
    [finalMutableArray addObject:[arrayTwo objectAtIndex:index]];
    [finalMutableArray addObject:[arrayThree objectAtIndex:index]];
}
NSArray *finalArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:finalMutableArray];
```

You will probably want to test that the arrays are of the same length. You cannot add `nil` to an `NSMutableArray` or `NSArray`. You can add an `NSNull` placeholder, but it's probably better to check your input.

Comment: I added a fix to the capacity value.

Answer (score 8):

`[@[@[@1,@2],@[@3,@4],@[@5,@6]] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"]`

So once you have a array of arrays you call `unionOfArrays` collection operator.

Comment: +1 for clever use of Key-Value encoding. You'd have to make sure none of your component parts are nil if you go this route.

Answer (score 3):

If you have array of arrays

```
NSArray *arrayOfArrays = ...;
NSMutableArray *oneArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSArray *tmpArray in arrayOfArrays) {
    [oneArray addObjectsFromArray:tmpArray];
}
```