# how to combining two static array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to combine two Static Arrays into another Static Array. My two static arrays are dailyPortfolioPrices1 & dailyPortfolio2.

```
- (NSArray *)dailyPortfolioPrices1  //my first array
{
    static NSArray *prices = nil;
    if (!prices)
    {
        prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:582.13],
                  [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:604.43],
                  [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.01],
                  nil];
    }
    return prices;

- (NSArray *)dailyPortfolioPrices2 //my second array
{
    static NSArray *prices2 = nil;
    if (!prices2)
    {
        prices2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:476.13],
                  [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:534.43],
                  [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.01],
                  nil];
    }
    return prices2;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to combine these two Arrays into an another array named dailyPortfolioPrices. And I need to display dailyPortfolioPrices using an index.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Please post code,not screenshot of code

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, in which language/script you are trying to combine two static arrays?

Comment: Does this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955250/how-to-merge-two-nsarray) ask a similar question? Also, I would check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190782/combining-multiple-nsarrays) as well.

Comment: I agree with @IBajwa - what language is this? I also stumbled on this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232959/objective-c-combine-multiple-string-arrays) that seemed similar.

Comment: You cannot combine those arrays as they are in different scopes.  Make them instance variables so any code in the class can access them.

Comment: @l00phole, two methods that return arrays can have their results combined into a single array.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *dailyPortfolioPrices=[[self dailyPortfolioPrices1] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[self dailyPortfolioPrices2]];
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

The arrays can be concatenated into a new array using

```
NSArray *dailyPortfolioPrices = [self.dailyPortfolioPrices1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.dailyPortfolioPrices2];
```

The values in the array can be retrieved along with their index using

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < dailyPortfolioPrices.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"index %ld, item %@", (long)i, [newArray objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

where I have added an `NSLog` to output the values to the console.

Comment: Those arrays are local and cannot be accessed from outside the method.

Comment: The arrays are passed as return values from their respective functions. They are not being accessed from inside the method.

Comment: Yeah that's certainly true.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you:

```
NSArray *dailyPortfolioPrices=[[self dailyPortfolioPrices1] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[self dailyPortfolioPrices2]];
```